# Problem with spacing for 6 tables in minipage

Tags: tables, minipage, overleaf

I am having problems with the right alignment of the 6 tables I have in my minipage. I tried reducing the space between the tables with `\vspace{-x}`, but this does not work everywhere. The tables that I have at the moment are:
[image]

However, the space between [a.23 a.24] and [a.25 a.26] is too large and I cannot find how to reduce it. The space that I used between A.24 and A.25 (above the first `\noindent` seems to reduce the space between [a.25 a.26] an [a.27 a.28]. How do I alter this, or is there maybe a smarter way to do this formatting? The source code that I used is below.

Edit: problem is fixed by removing the \vspace and [1\width]. Thanks for the help!

```
\section{Results molar mass gradient}
\begin{table}[hbt!]
\vspace{-20mm}
  {\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.5\textwidth}
       \centering
       \caption{Effectiveness factor of component A and percentage error for slow reaction.}
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l}
            \hline
            Model     & Effectiveness factor & Error {[}\%{]} \\ \hline
MS   & 0.98869 & 0      \\ \hline
FW   & 0.98868 & -0.001 \\ \hline
FW,M & 0.98867 & -0.002 \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \label{postertest1effectiveness}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill     
  {\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.45\textwidth}
       \centering
       \caption{Percentage error in fluxes at the edge of the particle for slow reaction.}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        Model     & Flux A & Flux B & Flux C   \\ \hline
MS   & 0      & 0      & 0      \\ \hline
FW   & 0.04   & 0.06   & 0.16   \\ \hline
FW,M & 0.06   & 0.07   & 0.11    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{postertest1fluxedge}
    \end{minipage}}
    \vspace{-20mm}
    \noindent
      {\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.5\textwidth}
       \centering
       \caption{Effectiveness factor of component A and percentage error for moderate reaction.}
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l}
            \hline
            Model     & Effectiveness factor & Error {[}\%{]} \\ \hline
MS   & 0.73   & 0      \\ \hline
FW   & 0.727  & -0.463 \\ \hline
FW,M & 0.725  & -0.649 \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \label{postertest1effectiveness}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill     
  {\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.45\textwidth}
       \centering
       \caption{Percentage error in fluxes at the edge of the particle for moderate reaction.}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        Model     & Flux A & Flux B & Flux C   \\ \hline
MS   & 0      & 0      & 0      \\ \hline
FW   & 0.12   & 0.05   & 0.67   \\ \hline
FW,M & 0.12   & 0.13   & 0.54   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{postertest1fluxedge}
    \end{minipage}}
    \vspace{-20mm}
    \noindent
      {\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.5\textwidth}
       \centering
       \caption{Effectiveness factor of component A and percentage error for fast reaction.}
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l}
            \hline
            Model     & Effectiveness factor & Error {[}\%{]} \\ \hline
MS   & 0.159  & 0      \\ \hline
FW   & 0.155  & -2.599 \\ \hline
FW,M & 0.155  & -2.471 \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \label{postertest1effectiveness}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill     
  {\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.45\textwidth}
       \centering
       \caption{Percentage error in fluxes at the edge of the particle for fast reaction.}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        Model     & Flux A & Flux B & Flux C   \\ \hline
MS   & 0      & 0      & 0      \\ \hline
FW   & 0.84   & 1.76   & 9.60  \\ \hline
FW,M & 1.66   & 2.12   & 3.88   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{postertest1fluxedge}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You may want to start by removing all occurrences of `\vspace{-20mm}` and `[1\width]`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and contains the necessary package.

Comment: Unrelated: place the  `label` command right after (or within) the `caption` command.

Comment: The problem is fixed by removing the \vspace and [1\width]. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

- You not provide any information about your document. Therefore I use `article` documentclass
- For table I use `tabularray` package (simpler and shorter code)
- For columns with numbers is used `S` columns, for which is used `tabularray` sintax `Q[c, si={table-format=1.3}]`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\section{Results molar mass gradient}
    \begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \centering
   \caption{Effectiveness factor of component A and percentage error for slow reaction.}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={l Q[c, si={table-format=1.5}] Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]},
             }
Model   & {{{Effectiveness factor}}} 
                    & {{{Error [\si{\%}]}}} \\
MS      & 0.98869   &  0                    \\
FW      & 0.98868   & -0.001                \\
FW,M    & 0.98867   & -0.002                \\ 
\end{tblr}
\label{postertest1effectiveness}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \centering
   \caption{Percentage error in fluxes at the edge of the particle for slow reaction.}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={l *{3}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}},
             }
Model   & {{{Flux A}}}
                & {{{Flux B}}}
                        & {{{Flux C}}}  \\ 
MS      & 0     & 0     & 0         \\  
FW      & 0.04  & 0.06  & 0.16      \\  
FW,M    & 0.06  & 0.07  & 0.11      \\  
\end{tblr}
\label{postertest1fluxedge}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \centering
   \caption{Effectiveness factor of component A and percentage error for moderate reaction.}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={l *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.3}]} },
             }
Model   & {{{Effectiveness factor}}}
                & {{{Error [\si{\%}]}}} \\
MS      & 0.73  & 0                     \\ 
FW      & 0.727 & -0.463                \\  
FW,M    & 0.725 & -0.649                \\  
\end{tblr}
\label{postertest1effectiveness}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \centering
   \caption{Percentage error in fluxes at the edge of the particle for moderate reaction.}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={l *{3}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}},
             }
Model   & {{{Flux A}}}
                & {{{Flux B}}}
                        & {{{Flux C}}}  \\
MS      & 0     & 0     & 0             \\  
FW      & 0.12  & 0.05  & 0.67          \\ 
FW,M    & 0.12  & 0.13  & 0.54          \\ 
\end{tblr}
\label{postertest1fluxedge}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \centering
   \caption{Effectiveness factor of component A and percentage error for fast reaction.}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={l *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.3}]}},
             }
Model   & {{{Effectiveness factor}}}
                & {{{Error [\si{\%}]}}} \\
MS      & 0.159 & 0                     \\ 
FW      & 0.155 & -2.599                \\
FW,M    & 0.155 & -2.471                \\
\end{tblr}
\label{postertest1effectiveness}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \centering
   \caption{Percentage error in fluxes at the edge of the particle for fast reaction.}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={l *{3}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}},
             }
Model   & {{{Flux A}}}
            & {{{Flux B}}}
                    & {{{Flux C}}}  \\
MS   & 0    & 0     & 0             \\
FW   & 0.84 & 1.76  & 9.60          \\
FW,M & 1.66 & 2.12  & 3.88          \\
\end{tblr}
\label{postertest1fluxedge}
\end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```